# How to test oracle packages with inner state?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, testing, oracle11g

Suppose we have an oracle package, which was initialized with some value grabbed from a table holding global parameters. Despite the fact that it is an ugly practice, it could work in production since the parameters are to be set during installation and not likely to change frequently. But when one is testing the package, it's needed to reinitialize its state before each case.

I tried two approaches:

1. execute immediate 'ALTER PACKAGE my_package COMPILE';
2. dbms_session.reset_package;

The first doesn't work in some rare cases (i don't know why).

The second resets all the packages touched by current session, including a package, which contains test cases, so any call of **reset_package** leads to abort execution of tests.

What do I need to correctly test a package with inner state, when there's a need to change the state during tests execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this. First of all, nobody prohibits you to publish an 'Initialize' subroutine and use it for re-reading variables before each test. It's a better way, I guess, but if you wish, you can add to this package something like

```
procedure MyPublicMethod is
begin
  if UnitTesting.RightNow then Initialize; end if;
  ...
end;
```

and got the same effect automatically.

Comment: Thank you, @Sanders. I expected it's possible to avoid changes in target package, but it looks like there's no way to do it beautiful (this word is not appreciated in PL/SQL).

Comment: You can try to avoid it using, say, jobs, but I guess it's loss of simplicity. Philosophy of unit testing orders to change source code if required.

Comment: I agree about simplicity. But another point in the philosophy is to run tests without global state. On the other hand, data bases are piles of global state, moreover PL/SQL doesn't provide any tools for mocking (and looks like it will never do since it is so ancient inside - I can smell punch cards from it). Seems to me I'm not gonna find simple and pure solution.